# MySQL Query for Library Database

Tags: mysql

I have a database project where I am struggling with three queries. Could you please help?

I have the following tables:

```
member(memberNo, name, age)
book(isbn, title, author, publisher, year, category)
borrowed(memberNo, isbn, date)
```

And I have to answer each of the following questions by formulating a single SQL query (i.e. not to use views):

1) For each category, find the names of members who have borrowed more than five books in that category.

2) Find the most prolific author in the library, i.e., the author who has authored the most books.

3) Find the names of members who have borrowed the same book more than once.

thanks a lot

**So far I have tried the following:**

1) My Query:

```
SELECT member.name 
  FROM member 
 WHERE member.memberNo IN(SELECT borrowed.memberNo 
                            FROM borrowed 
                           GROUP 
                              BY memberNo 
                          HAVING COUNT(memberNo)>5)
```

Result:
This seems to return the correct result, but I haven’t figured out how to add ‘category’ as per the question.

2) My Query:

```
SELECT author 
     , COUNT(*) AS 'Books Written' 
  FROM book 
 GROUP 
    BY author 
HAVING COUNT(isbn)>6
```

Result:
This returns the correct result, but only because I have specified more than 6  – and that is because I know that I have an author who has written 7 books, therefore I am specifying ‘more than 6’ – but I am not sure how to write a query that will determine ‘most books written’ by itself

3) My Query:

```
SELECT member.name 
  FROM member 
 WHERE member.memberNo IN (SELECT borrowed.memberNo 
                             FROM borrowed 
                            WHERE borrowed.isbn IN(
                                   SELECT COUNT(borrowed.isbn) as 'con' 
                                     FROM borrowed 
                                    WHERE 'con' >1))
```

Result:
The query returns some rows with member names, but they are not correct – some of the members have simply borrowed more than one book (but not the same book more than once) but other members have not borrowed any books more than once – so the query is not correct.

Comment: This looks like homework assignment, so I'll only give you few hints what to look for: SQL joins, order by, count, having. All are basic SELECT SQL syntax.

Comment: Could you show us what you have so far? and maybe what errors you are getting? @frin nice guy

Comment: Create the metadata first and i promise you i help !! kkk - i wanna se those constraints

Comment: frin's point about JOINs must be emphasised. My generation has the advantage that subqueries syntax didn't exist when we started (only a few years ago). It would be best if this stuff could be hidden away until the basics had been mastered. Oh, and don't use Word for writing queries. Use a basic coding text editor (FWIW, I use TextPad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a clue for 1....

```
SELECT b.something
     , c.something_else
  FROM a
  JOIN b
    ON b.x = a.x
  JOIN c
    ON c.y = a.y
 GROUP 
    BY b.m
     , c.n
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5;
```

Comment: Hi Strawberry, thanks for the clue, I've come up with the following which seem to be correct: SELECT Book.Category, Member.Name 
FROM Member join Borrowed on  Member.MemberNo = Borrowed.MemberNo join Book on Borrowed.ISBN = Book.ISBN 
GROUP by Book.Category, Member.Name 
HAVING COUNT(*) >5

Comment: Looks pretty good to me! Note that we don't know how to account for the possibility that the same reader borrowed the same book twice. The DISTINCT operator can help with that.